# I've got Models/Controllers, but how do I handle views?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, java-ee-6

If I'm using `HttpServlet`'s for my controllers, and I've got my models setup and in a specific package, what about the views?  The last thing I want is to dump all of this HTML into my controllers.  Where do I put it?  What file types?

I'm new to Java :)

**Update**

If I should be using jsp files, wouldn't having jsp files within my "Web Pages" section make them publicly viewable?  Or should they go somewhere else?  How do I include them on my page and pass parameters to them?

Comment: Can you use jsp? Its inverse of servlet where you embed java in html.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 2):

If you are using servlets (which seems to be the case), your view should go in [JSP](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jsp/index.html) files. If you are using [JSF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html), you put your view in facelets, but it is not the case since you are using servlets. JSF is the most recent specification, but I bet it is better to start by JSPs and servlets - maybe following the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/).

**EDIT**: how to dispatch a request from the servlet to a JSP? Just get a `RequestDispatcher` from the `ServletRequest` passing the JSP path as parameter:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
```

If the dispatcher is different from `null`, just call its <del>`include()`</del> `forward()` method:

```
dispatcher.forward(request, response);`
```

The dispatcher can be `null` (for example, if the JSP does not exist) so it is a good practice to verify if a proper dispatcher was returned.

Comment: So how do I tell the HttpServlet to use those .jsp files?  Do the .jsp files go into the "Web Pages" section?  Wouldn't that make them globally accessible if you put in the correct URL?

Comment: I've looked through a lot of that tutorial and haven't been able to pinpoint my answer

Comment: You should not include the view. You should forward to the view. Read the javadocs of the both methods to understand the important difference.

Comment: @BalusC you are completely right, as usual. Sorry for my little mistake - today I work exclusively writing portlets, where the `forward()` method is not useful and the `include()` is ubiquitous, so I allowed my custom to guide my question. Thank you for your warning, I repaired the question.

Answer (score 0):

[jsps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) or javascript if you are going for a rich internet application (RIA).

You most likely want jsps.

Answer (score 0):

JSPs are for views. So they should be public. JSPs dont expose anything except for html that your output just as you would in PHP. The source does not show unless you have configured your server incorrectly.

Also you can pass objects from servlet to jsp through shared objects as they are in same vm. JSP is servlet reversed so instead of printing HTML from java you embed Java in html which saves you from writing out.print statements....

So servlets are more suited to write actions. JSP for views.

Answer (score 0):

You might also look into spending some time learning JSTL too.  It makes your JSPs clean and readable: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html

Keep in mind, a user will not be able to see the code in your JSP, the web container actually compiles the JSP file much like the JVM (actually in a very similar fashion) compiles source code.  If you are using something like Tomcat, you can look at a compiled JSP in the work directory of your web container.  It will look surprisingly like a normal class file with a lot of out.write's in it.